# How to catch the regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I have a string like below:

`"This is the code: cd001, cd002, cd003 "`

(i already catch: cd001, cd002, cd003)

but it's must ignore for: cd001, cd002, cd003 in the string below

`"This is the code: cd001,cd002, cd003,xxxx "`

i have a regex: `[^|\\s|>]*([a-z]{2}[0-9]+\\.?)\\b`

*(Begin with start string, space then two lowercase letters, digits after, and then is [. or , or # or space] )*

Comment: Could you reformat your question, and clearly state inputs and expected matches?

Comment: i already fix my question, hope it's better!

Comment: Why should it ignore the second input? What are the rules? Your two inputs are quite the same...

Comment: Can you post few examples of input, expected output and logic behind decision that this output is expected?

Comment: i have updated the question, can you look on it?

Answer (score 0):

```
// parse inputString into String[] of codes
// if there are no codes in the string, codes[0] is ""
String[] codes =
// delete beginning of the line till ":" inclusive
    inputString.replaceFirst("^.*: ", "").
// delete two codes that are separated by "," and
// followed by 0 or 1 "," and 1 " "
    replaceAll("[a-z0-9]+,[a-z0-9]+,? ", "").
// delete trailing spaces
    replaceFirst(" +$", "").
// split codes
    split(", ");
```